# Is $\liminf \frac{\sigma_{k}(n)}{n}$ finite for every $k$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples

Can someone show me how to prove that $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma_{k}(n)}{n} < \infty$$ for every natural number $k$? Or is this problem open?
Here, $\sigma_{k}(n)=\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(\dots n)))$ is the $k$-th iterate of the sum of divisors function.

Note: I think for $k=2$ this had been proved by Makowski and Schinzel and the limit equals $1$.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: @Ricardo Andrade: I changed back $\sigma_k(n)$ to its originally intended meaning. For the sum of $k$-th powers of $n$ it is trivial that the liminf is infinite.

Comment: @GH from MO, thank you very much for your correction. I apologize for my mistaken description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an open problem, only known for $k=1,2$.

Both the conjecture and the known cases are due to Schinzel.

You can find a nice survey here: "[On the third iterates of the φ- and σ-functions](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.desklight-3dd8ec9f-5996-4945-a5ee-ac422cd6097a)" H. Maier (1984)

It shouldn't be hard to find more recent references that mention it as open.

Comment: and Maier has used sieve methods to prove the result for k = 3.